# Phonegap Build InAppBrowser

Tags: sencha-touch, cordova, phonegap-build

It is necessary to add any specific setting in config.xml to have inAppBrowser working with phonegap build?

Im just adding:

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank');
```

or

```
var ref = window.open(url, 'blank');
```

but it doesnt work.

My config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id = "com.phonegap.myapp">
    <name>My app</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.7.0" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this which will open the in-app browser:

```
 window.open(destination, '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

In your config.xml you should have a lot more than what you have there.  This is mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget>
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />

<content src="index.html" />

<plugins>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
    <plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
    <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</plugins>

<access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Yours might be smaller if you don't use all of the features of PhoneGap.  You'll definitely need that InAppBrowser plugin however!